# Second button click not working

Tags: javascript

First click works and opens a web page. Second click and no event. Why is the second event not executed: t2.firstChild.nodeValue = "two";1
        window.open("http://www.google.com",'content');?
First click should open a web page(1), the second should open another webpage(2). Third time should open first web page(1).

```
<!doctype html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#sidhuvud {
    background: #cc99cc;
    padding: 20px;
}
#kolumn1 {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 550px;
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
#kolumn2 {
float: left;
    width: 60%;
    min-height: 550px;
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
#kolumn3 {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 550px;
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>

<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidhuvud">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id="kolumn1">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<div id="kolumn2">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><br> 

<div id="content"><iframe name="content" width="850" height="500" src="http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/215340-open-href-into-a-div/" style="display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;"></iframe></div>

</div>


<div id="kolumn3">
    <ul>

<table id="outside">
    <tr><td id="t1"><li class="button3">Test me</li></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="t2">one</td></tr>
</table>

</ul>
<br>

<div id="log"></div>

<script>
//test button
// Function to change the content of t2
function modifyText() {
  var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
  if (t2.firstChild.nodeValue == "two") {
    t2.firstChild.nodeValue = "one";    
    window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","content");
  } else {
    t2.firstChild.nodeValue = "two";1
    window.open("http://www.google.com",'content');
  }
}

//test button
// add event listener to table
var el = document.getElementById("outside");
el.addEventListener("click", modifyText, false);

</script>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<li>` can't be a child of `<td>`. That might be an issue because the browser might render it's own `<ul>` around your `<li>` which will make `t2.firstChild.nodeValue` undefined or something. And the random `1` in your code might cause an issue too. Remove it.

Comment: Try to load a different website, some websites (including Google) don't let you open them in an iframe.

Comment: Your HTML has more than one error, fix those first.

Comment: Thanks. I've tested more, with another script without faults and also other browsers. I get the same problem. So it has to be the iframe. Can the iframe be replaced with a div that does the same?